# MS Excel - Unable to import data as text/csv file

Tags: excel, csv, stock, office-2016, vba

I am trying to import data from yahoo finance. However, when I go to

Data >> From text/CSV and enter the link, the following screen pops up:

[image: Pop_UP 1]

[image: Pop_UP_2]

The link I enter is just a copied link from yahoo finance (i.e. yahoo finacne >> google >> historical price >> download data >> copy link address).

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoeIn-3jbhI&t=19s ---> I am following a Youtube Video tutorial for importing stock. Unlike in the video @ 2:59, I get the pop up screen (image attached in the post).

Comment: I am getting the same, not sure why. The video is using Excel 2007, maybe it works different with later versions.

Comment: You can import from the Web page by using the **from Web** import wizard; the URL being the URL on the page that is displaying the historical quotes; and selecting the proper table (Table 2 when I tried it)

Answer (score 2):

The video you linked to in your comment has been shot with Excel 2007, so it is about software that is 10 years behind what you are using. It was published three years ago. Things have changed since then.

Yahoo Finance API is no longer a free service. They shut down the service earlier this year and you can no longer pull data from it with Excel.

Apart from that, if you run the most recent versions of Excel 2016, the icon to import text or CSV will now start the Get & Transform functionality, also known as Power Query, not the old text import wizard. The dialogs that you see are from Get & Transform, asking you to authenticate for the URL you entered. If you have a user name and password, enter it and the connection will be made.

If you want to use the old text import wizard, you need to go File > Options > Data and tick the box for "From Text (Legacy)".

[image]

Then you can use the drop-down option for Legacy Wizards in the Get Data dialog of Get & Transform.

[image]

But I doubt that this will work, since Yahoo Finance has shut down the service.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please take the time to mark the answer as described in the [Tour]. That is how you can say Thanks around here.